# MySQL: Get results only if there is specific user id or user id is null

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, where-clause

We have two tables:

- Competitions
- Results

We need to display competition id, two opponents, date from Competitions table and result, user id from Results table. We'll be searching by Results and if user has already submitted his result then we display his id and result. Else we just display null in those two fields but there must not be any result of any other user then this one which we provide. I came up with this query, but it's not showing all competitions if there is not provided some user's id which has already submitted it's result.

```
SELECT c.competition_id, c1.name AS first, c2.name AS second, c.date, r.result_id, r.user_id 
FROM competitions c
JOIN countries c1 ON c.first=c1.country_id
JOIN countries c2 ON c.second=c2.country_id
LEFT JOIN results r ON c.competition_id=r.competition_id
WHERE c.date='2013-07-04' AND (r.user_id=1 OR r.user_id IS NULL)
```

What do I have to do to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to move the `r.user_id` comparison into the `on` clause:

```
SELECT c.competition_id, c1.name AS first, c2.name AS second, c.date, r.result_id, r.user_id 
FROM competitions c
JOIN countries c1 ON c.first=c1.country_id
JOIN countries c2 ON c.second=c2.country_id
LEFT JOIN results r ON c.competition_id=r.competition_id and r.user_id = 1
WHERE c.date='2013-07-04'
```

This will keep all competitions, but return results only for the given user.

I believe your query is filtering out `results` where someone other than the user has submitted results.  This is because there is a match on the row, so `r.user_id` is not `NULL`.  However, the user id does not match the one you are looking for either.